# Kendo UI Chart - Want tooltip to always show

Tags: kendo-ui

I need some help with how Kendo Chart tool.
I am trying to plot a line graph with bookings on particular date. I have a booking on a particular day and can see the circular plot. If i hover on it i can see the tool tip which contains the summary of the booking. I want this tooltip to always be visible/open. At the moment it only happens on mouse over.

```js
function createChart() {
    $("#chart").kendoChart(data);
                     var tooltip = $("#chart").kendoTooltip({
                        width: 120,
                        position: "top",
                       visibe: true
                    }).data("kendoTooltip");
 
}
```

I am using Kendo for the first time and am very confused now. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: if you dont want the tooltip to close onmouse out, just add attribute autohide : false on the tooltip initialization

Comment: Why not just turn on labels for the series: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/line-charts/local-data-binding  You can use templates or format to show what you want and it is always visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always show the tooltips or labels without having to hover over them by mouse, by using setting the visible of the series labels to true as follows:

```
seriesDefaults: {
                type: "line",
                labels: {
                    visible: true
                }
            }
```

You can check and see a demo example here: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/line-charts/local-data-binding